# If (or maybe hasClass) is being ignored - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[You may understand this better by checking the CodePen version.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGyMjX)

Going straight to the point, the issue is: when you go to the second or third "slide" (the reddish or bluish colors), and then attempt to resize your window, its interior will become grayish~black. That's not supposed to happen.

The black~gray content must stay within the black~gray "slide", the red in the red one, the blue in the blue one.

I'm making a site which follows this logic, but with images. I made this codepen to simplify since my code is awfully complicated and there's tons of unnecessary code.

I believe the problem is in the if($('body').hasClass('first')){if$(window).resize(function... etc; because the if seems to be ignored since the #glasses div is always gray/black if you resize your window.

Since I'm a beginner in Javascript I don't see anything wrong, in fact I just can't understand why something as simple as a if wouldn't work.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```js
var nums = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
var curr = 0;

$('.next, .prev').on('click', function(e) {
  var offset = $(this).hasClass('prev') ? nums.length - 1 : 1;
  curr = (curr + offset) % nums.length;
  $('body').removeClass();
  $('body').addClass(nums[curr]);

  if ($('body').hasClass('first')) {
    if ($(window).width() >= 1367) {
      $("#glasses").css("background", "#000");
    } else {
      $("#glasses").css("background", "#666");
    }
    event.preventDefault();
  } else if ($('body').hasClass('second')) {
    if ($(window).width() >= 1367) {
      $("#glasses").css("background", "#00f");
    } else {
      $("#glasses").css("background", "#66f");
    }
    event.preventDefault();
  } else {

    if ($(window).width() >= 1367) {
      $("#glasses").css("background", "#f00");
    } else {
      $("#glasses").css("background", "#6ff");
    }
    event.preventDefault();
  };

})
if ($('body').hasClass('first')) {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() >= 1367) {
      $("#glasses").css("background", "#000");
    } else {
      $("#glasses").css("background", "#666");
    }
  })
} else if ($('body').hasClass('second')) {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() >= 1367) {
      $("#glasses").css("background", "#00f");
    } else {
      $("#glasses").css("background", "#66f");
    }
  })
} else if ($('body').hasClass('third')) {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() >= 1367) {
      $("#glasses").css("background", "f00");
    } else {
      $("#glasses").css("background", "6ff");
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.slides-navigation a{
   top: 50%;
    position: fixed;
}
.prev{
 left:30px;
 position:absolute;
}
.next{
 right: 45px;
 position:absolute;
}
#glasses{
   width: 50%;
    height: 450px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #000;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 42% 86%;
}
.first{
  border: #000 16px solid;
}
.second{
  border: #00f 16px solid;
}
.third{
   border: #f00 16px solid;
}
@media screen and (max-width:1367px){
  .first{
    border: #666 16px solid;
  }
  .second{
    border: #66f 16px solid;
  }
  .third{
    border: #6ff 16px solid;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="first">
  <div id="glasses"></div>
   <nav class="slides-navigation desktop">    
          <a href="#" class="prev">Prev></a>
          <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
   </nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the problem revolves around the `$(window).resize` functions being inside of the `if` statements, rather than the other way around.

It should look more like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($('body').hasClass('first')) {
      if ($(window).width() >= 1367) {
        $("#glasses").css("background", "#000");
      } else {
        $("#glasses").css("background", "#666");
      }
  } else if ($('body').hasClass('second')) {
      if ($(window).width() >= 1367) {
        $("#glasses").css("background", "#00f");
      } else {
        $("#glasses").css("background", "#66f");
      }
  } else if ($('body').hasClass('third')) {
      if ($(window).width() >= 1367) {
        $("#glasses").css("background", "f00");
      } else {
        $("#glasses").css("background", "6ff");
      }
  }
});
```

Otherwise your code checks for for the body's class once, applies the resize function for only that class, and never knows to check again.

Comment: That solved it. I don't really get why it doesn't check for the class again since there's an else if, but at least now I know when the code doesn't work, it may be an order of appearance issue.

Comment: @AndreaSantana it's due to how event listeners work. `$(window).resize(` is letting the browser know that you'd like something to happen on the `resize` event, but it only knows to fire whatever is in the `function(){}` that you pass as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement

```
if ($('body').hasClass
```

Is only being run once, when the page loads.

You should move this into the next/prev event handler, so it re-calculates the resize event every time.